# Json file based Question and answering model using VertexAI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, nlp-question-answering, chromadb, semantic-search

I'm working on document based question and answering model using vertexAI.. But here I'm using Json file instead of document such as PDF or DOCS. Consider that, the 1000s of json file which contains the specific customer information. So I need to use with vertexAI.

I have already referred the below document, Although they used Docs.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/language/use-cases/document-qa/question_answering_documents_langchain.ipynb

Below is the flow of program,
reading json file --> converting into Chunks ---> Storing in chromaDB ---> using vertexAI answering the user question from the json file

Can someone suggest any idea?